# Regex to remove text between tags in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have a code like this

```
<wp:post_name>artifical-sweeteners-ruin-your-health</wp:post_name>
```

I want to change it to

```
<wp:post_name></wp:post_name>
```

removing everything inside the tag.

Comment: Please edit your question. Your question is incomplete

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Search for

```
<wp:post_name>[^<>]+</wp:post_name>
```

and replace all with

```
<wp:post_name></wp:post_name>
```

This assumes that tags can't be nested (which makes the regex quite safe to use). If other tags may be present, then you need to search for

```
(?i)<wp:post_name>.*?</wp:post_name>
```

instead (same replace string). However, this probably only works in the latest versions of Notepad++ which brought a major regex engine overhaul, and it's a bit riskier because it will mess up your file if nested `<wp:post_name>` tags can occur.

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for. This worked well in BBedit for Mac using `grep` in the find and replace function.